# prototype chain fails to retrieve a property set in Function.prototype

Tags: javascript

When I add a property to `Function.prototype`, why does it disappear from the chain?
Why is the property `yyy` (which is in the property chain) undefined?

```js
function Shape() { }
Shape.prototype.xxx = 111;
Function.prototype.yyy = 222;

let x = new Shape;

console.log(x.xxx) // 111
console.log(x.yyy) // undefined???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Function.prototype` is only on the prototype chain of *functions*, so it's not in the prototype chain of your `x` object, because that isn't a function. (And yes, this is a bit confusing.)

The `prototype` property of a function `X` is used to set the prototype of an object created via `new X` or `Object.create(X)`.

Your `Shape.prototype`'s prototype is `Object.prototype`, not `Function.prototype`. (`Function.prototype` is the prototype of `Shape`, the function.)

Your code creates two prototype chains, one for the function `Shape` and one for `Shape.prototype` (and `x`):

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Shape         |   +−−−>| Function.prototype | 
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−|   |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
| [[Prototype]] |−−−+    | [[Prototype]]      |−−−+
| prototype     |−−−+    | yyy: 222           |   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
                    |                              \    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     \   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−>|  Object.prototype  |
                      +−>| Shape.prototype    |    /    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
                    |    | [[Prototype]]      |−−−+
                    |    | xxx: 111           |
                    |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
|       x       |   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
| [[Prototype]] |−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

As you can see, since `Function.prototype` isn't in `x`'s chain, `x.yyy` is `undefined`. But `Shape.yyy` is, since `Shape` inherits from `Function.prototype`:

```js
function Shape() { }
Shape.prototype.xxx = 111;
Function.prototype.yyy = 222;

let x = new Shape;

console.log(x.xxx);     // 111
console.log(x.yyy);     // undefined
console.log(Shape.yyy); // 222
```

Comment: FWIW, a fun thing about JavaScript's new(ish) `class` syntax is that constructors for derived classes inherit from their parent, so static methods and properties are inherited. E.g., `class B extends A` means that `B`'s prototype is `A`.  FWIW, I got into that in the chapter on classes (Chapter 4) in my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.